# makeStyles in Material-ui need to use so many ( !important <= css code ) to style mui components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm now trying to create a website using **material-ui** with **react**.
I needed to add my own style to mui components. For this purpose, I used the makeStyle from '@mui',
But
The problem is that if I want to make changes to the material components, I have to use the ( !important ) with each stage.

so here is simple example:

**App.js**

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  btn: {
    backgroundColor: "red !important",
  },
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" className={classes.btn}>
        Click me
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

if i want to change the <Button> background i must use **!important** with *css code* .
so What do I have to do now ???

versions:
"@mui/material": "^5.4.4",
"@mui/styles": "^5.5.1",

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting new app, new MaterialUI version recommend not to use `useStyles` but use `styled-components` or `EmotionJS`.
Anyways if you want to use `useStyles` try to wrap your app in `<StylesProvider injectFirst></StylesProvider>` from mui. It should inject your styles first and `!important` shouldnt be needed.

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion, now i am using Styled-component but I've faced the same problem with styled-component, when i want to change the <Button /> background i must use ( important ) so i asked the question in stackOverflow here is the question, and i'm sorry to upset you but i hope give me a time and asnwering me :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71627037/styled-components-doesnt-work-with-material-ui