# styled-components doesn't work with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

my question is what is the different between this two { styled }??

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
 
and

import styled from "styled-components";
```

---------------------------

hi friends,

i am using material-ui with reactjs to create a website, then i want to add my custom style with help styled-component to the material-ui components ( Specifically, I want to change the AppBar style ) .

*But I faced 2 problem.*

1. First problem

i am try to create my custom design with styled-component library:

> ```
> import styled from "styled-components";
> ```

but i must use so many ( !important ) to change the design, like this:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import AppBar from "@mui/material"

const CustomNavbar = styled(AppBar)`
  background-color: red !important;
  position: relative !important;
  color: yellow !important;
`;
```

2.Second Problem - ( it is work without any problem )

i searched for custom styling mui-components then i use the { styled } from mui,

> ```
> import { styled } from "@mui/system";
> ```

and it is work without any problem ..

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import AppBar from "@mui/material"

const CustomNavbar = styled(AppBar)`
  background-color: red;
  position: relative ;
  color: yellow;
`;
```

so my question is

what is the different between this two { styled }??

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
 
and

import styled from "styled-components";
```

Thank you very much for giving me time and answering this question.

Comment: This `import AppBar from "@mui/material"` should be like this `import { AppBar } from "@mui/material"`. If you want to import anything else you can do: `import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';` Also try adding the styles using the structure shown in the documentation. https://mui.com/system/styled/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is section in documentation of MUI about that, if you need to get rid of `important`, you need to wrap you app in

```
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      {/* Your component tree. Now you can override MUI's styles. */}
</StyledEngineProvider>
```

from `mui`, because it will change order of importing styles.

source:  https://mui.com/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order